# Virtual function not returning the value from the concrete function

Tags: return-value, virtual-functions

I'm working off of a program that I didn't code, but I want (need) to understand. It is in C++ in the context of virtual functions.

At one point it sets up the virtual boolean function "acceptReject" as shown here.

```
virtual bool acceptReject(const Double& DeltaH) const = 0;
```

Then it sets that virtual boolean to be the concrete boolean function "globalMetropolisAcceptReject" as shown here:

```
bool acceptReject(const Double& DeltaH) const {
  globalMetropolisAcceptReject(DeltaH);
}
```

If I call globalMetropolisAcceptReject directly, everything works. If I call acceptReject (the virtual function) it enters and processes the code correctly, but it doesn't pass the value back. Instead, it always gives false.

Any guesses as to what is missing?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that I just needed to add the word return in the implementation.

```
    bool acceptReject(const Double& DeltaH) const {
  return globalMetropolisAcceptReject(DeltaH);
}
```

Is proper protocol to delete the question or ?